# Wrap rxjs subscription in extension method to return new model

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, typescript-generics

I've inherited an API that returns a custom `Response` wrapper object for every endpoint response. I am building an Angular application to get data from this API and have defined a similar `Response` type in my Typescript.

```
export class Response<T> {
    code: number;
    data: T;
    message?: string;
}
```

When I make an API call I get back the appropriate response in JSON.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

this.http.post<Response<Data>>(url, payload).subscribe({  // Type defined here (Data)
   next: (response) => {
       if (response.code === 200) {
           this.data = response.data;  // This is not typed, returns Object, but everything works
       }
   }
})
```

First thing I noticed is when the response comes back from the Angular http call it is not actually typed.  It is only an `Object` and I am unable to enforce other extension methods to verify the response came back successful or parse for further error handling.

A solution I came up with is to wrap this call in something I can type myself to get the actual typed object to work with as well as handle any errors (`Response` returning null or BadDataException, etc.)

```
export function typeSubscribe<T>(
    this: Observable<Response<T>>,
    next?: (value: T) => void,
    error?: (error: T) => void,
    complete?: () => void
): Subscription {

    let newNext: (value: T) => void = next;

    if (next) {
        newNext = (value: T): void => {
            value = buildReponse<T>(value);
            if (value.code !== 200) {
                error(value.message);
                return;
            }
            next(value.data);
        };
    }

    const sub = this.subscribe({ next: newNext, error, complete });
    return sub;
}

function buildReponse<T>(body: any): Response<T> {
    const response = new Response<T>();
    if (!body) {
        response.code = 500;
        response.message = 'Response is empty';
        response.data = null;
        return response;
    }
    response.code = body.code;
    response.message = body.message;
    response.data = map<T>(body.data, body.data.constructor);   // body.data is Object or Array, whatever comes back from API
    return response;
}

// This function just returns empty Object {}
function map<T>(values: any, ctor: new () => T): T {
    const instance = new ctor();
    return Object.keys(instance).reduce((acc: any, key: string) => {
        acc[key] = values[key];
        return acc;
    }, {}) as T;
 }
```

With the intent to use it like so

```
this.http.post<Response<Data>>(url, payload).typeSubscribe((response) => {
   this.data = response;  // this.data will now be fully typed as `Data` and handled appropriately
})
```

My question:

1. There does not seem to be a way that `typeSubscribe` knows what `T` is.  It seems to have no knowledge of it at runtime even though somewhere in the IDE compiler, IntelliSense knows about it at each step. How is it possible to instantiate this type in Typescript at this point in the code (from the Http response).
2. It would be nice if I can handle the `Response` object and only deliver the `data` when it is successful. Is it possible to extend the subscribe to have an observable of one type (`Response<T>`) and return only the `T`?  The subscribe seems to require the Observable type `this` to match what is returned from `next`.  It is possible to make them different types?

I'm not worried about proper error handling or logging at this point, just trying to get the typing system tp work and understand subscribes at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are adding complexity to solve a simple thing! Kindly just add the type if its not identified, as to why its happening, I am unable to check that unless its replicated on a stackblitz, it can be multiple reasons, kindly check the below stackblitz where its working fine, please try to replicate the issue and share it back.

temporary fix

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

this.http.post<Response<Data>>(url, payload).subscribe({  // Type defined here (Data)
   next: (response: Data) => {
       if (response.code === 200) {
           this.data = response.data;  // This is not typed, returns Object, but everything works
       }
   }
})
```

ts - issue not reproducible!

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  HttpClient,
  HttpClientModule,
  provideHttpClient,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import 'zone.js';

export class Response<T> {
  code!: number;
  data!: T;
  message?: string;
}

export interface Data {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  userId: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [HttpClientModule],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  data!: Data;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http
      .post<Response<Data>>('https://dummyjson.com/posts/add', {
        title: 'I am in love with someone.',
        userId: 5,
      })
      .subscribe({
        // Type defined here (Data)
        next: (response) => {
          console.log(response);
          if (response.code === 200) {
            this.data = response!.data; // This is not typed, returns Object, but everything works
          }
        },
      });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideHttpClient()],
});
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cdbk6j?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Answer (score 1):

Angular "transpile" to javaScript, so it's not possible force a type. You can write to help you and the "compiler" check errors, but always can return "anything".

You can use "map" to return the data

```
this.http.post<Data>(url, payload).map((response: Response<Data>)=>{
   return response.code==200?response.data as Data:null
}).subscribe({
   next: (response: Data) => {
           this.data = response.data;
       }
   }
})
```

Really you should to have a service. Remember: "services return observables, you subscribe in the component"

Your service have a function like

```
postData<T>(url:string,arg:any):Observable<T>
{
    this.http.post<T>(url, arg).map((response: Response<T>)=>{
       return response.code==200?response.data as T:null
    })
}
```

And you use in your component

```
this.serviceData.postData<Data>(url,payload).subscribe({
       next: (response: Data) => {
               this.data = response.data;
           }
       }
)
```

Comment: I like this approach and just manually mapping it before it gets returned.  However, this still fails to compile with the following problem and being unable to cast T:

`Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<Response<T>, T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<T, T>'.
  Type 'Response<T>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Response<T>'.ts(2345)`